# Change form submit from image to text link

Tags: html, forms

I have a search form that has a image as the button which is great, but i can't get the image to look the same as other text, i would like to remove this image and just use it as text instead then style it accordingly, if someone could give me some advice on doing this the simplest way possible that would be appreciated.

```
<form action=".php" method="get" onsubmit="return check_small_search_form()">
  <label for="search_query"></label>
  <input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" class="Textbox" value="Search" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="image" src="Search.gif" class="Button">
</form>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Please can you add in a screen shot of what the image looks like - I will then give you the code for the styleing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the image with a submit button and remove the borders and background with css. That should show just plain text

```
<form action=".php" method="get" onsubmit="return check_small_search_form()">
  <label for="search_query"></label>
<input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" class="Textbox" value="Search" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="submit" value="The text you want" class="Button" />
</form>
```